# Converting a string back into an array

Tags: arrays, variables, swift

I have a variable that has a string thats has an array in it. How do I convert it to just an array again in swift?

```
var featCatName2 = "[home, pages, books, stores, groups, trips]"
```

Convert to:

```
var featCatName2 = [home, pages, books, stores, groups, trips]
```

Comment: *Why* do you store the array as a string like this? What if one of the strings contains a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is this one-liner:

```
var featCatName2 = "[home, pages, books, stores, groups, trips]"
let result = featCatName2.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]")).componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
```

This is also safe to call even when the array is empty :)

1. `var featCatName2 = "[home, pages, books, stores, groups, trips]"`
   Declare your string "array"
2. `featCatName2 = featCatName2.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]"))`
   Trim away [] in both ends.
3. `let result = featCatName2.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")`
   Explode the string into an array of strings.

Comment: I was just going to suggest this. I'd probably make it a two-liner, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
public extension String {
    var count: Int {
        return countElements(self)
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(Array(self)[i])
    }
    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        var start = advance(startIndex, r.startIndex)
        var end = advance(startIndex, r.endIndex)
        return substringWithRange(Range(start: start, end: end))
    }
}

var featCatName2 = "[home, pages, books, stores, groups, trips]"

let resultArray = featCatName2[1...featCatName2.count-2].componentsSeparatedByString(", ") // ["home", "pages", "books", "stores", "groups", "trips"]
```